# Laravel 7. How to fetch records from various tables using foreign key in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Laravel 7 and 2 tables: comp, computers.

I would like to display in the view index.blade.php the name of the computer e.g. DELL, IBM, LENOWO instead of id of this name.
What the foreach syntax should look like to retrieve the computer name from the computers table.

And when you add a new PC, what should the dropdownlist look like?

```
 class CreateCompTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comp', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('name_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('number');
            $table->string('year');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('name_id')->references('id')->on('computers')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

Table Computers

```
class CreateComputersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('computers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

CompControllers

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Comp;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CompController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $comp = Comp::latest()->paginate(5);

        return view('comp.index',compact('comp'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('comp.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name_id' => 'required',
            'number' => 'required',
            'year' => 'required',

        ]);

        comp::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('comp.index')
            ->with('success','xxx.');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Comp  $comp
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Comp $comp)
    {

        return view('comp.show',compact('comp'));
    }
```

View index.blade.php

```
@extends('comp.layout')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Comp</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('comp.create') }}"> Add comp</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>L.p</th>
           
            <th>Name comp</th>
            <th>Number comp</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th width="250px">Acction</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($comp as $comp)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
            <td>{{ $comp->name_id }}</td>

            <td>{{ $comp->number }}</td>

            <td>{{ $comp->year }}</td>

            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('comp.destroy',$comp->id) }}" method="POST">

                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('comp.show',$comp->id) }}">View</a>

                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('comp.edit',$comp->id) }}">Edit</a>

                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>


                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>



@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `Comp` model,  make a `belongsTo` relation :

```
public function computer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Computer', 'name_id');
}
```

Now you can access this relation,  from your blade, as:

```
@foreach($comp as $comp)
  <tr>
     <td>{{ $comp->computer->name }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try to view the view, I have a message: ErrorException
Trying to get property 'computer' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel7\resources\views\comp\index.blade.php)

Comment: I think you are trying to display a model's value which is null check your database

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It works as it should.
I still have a request as when adding a new computer to choose a computer from the drop-down list.